# MySQL SUM values from the same column if their id match

Tags: mysql

I would like to query a table where I would like to sum values from the same column / columns if their IDs match.

The table looks like this:

```
id | product_id | attribute_id | production_price | warehouse_id | qty | sell_qty
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 111          | 100.0000         | 1            | 50  | 45
2  | 1          | 111          | 100.0000         | 2            | 40  | 40
3  | 2          | 222          | 100.0000         | 1            | 30  | 20
4  | 2          | 222          | 100.0000         | 2            | 20  | 20
```

What I'm trying to do is sum the values of `qty` and `sell_qty` if the same products are in both warehuse(warehouse_id 1/2) and where product_id and attribute_id matches.
Something like this as a result:

```
product_id | attribute_id | production_price | qty | sell_qty
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 111          | 100.0000         | 90  | 85
2          | 222          | 100.0000         | 50  | 40
```

How can I do a query like this if its possible?

Comment: sum is add, not multiply

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a simple `group by`:

```
select product_id, attribute_id, production_price, sum(qty) qty, sum(sell_qty) sell_qty
from mytable
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong your answer does not take the warehouse in account. Because this way the whole table will return as result and not only thoese which are in warehuse_id = 1 and also in warehouse_id=2

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT sum(qty),sum(sell_qty) from table where warehouse_id = 1 group by product_id;
```

so it will sum the qty and sell-qty if there is a sale of same product under same warehouse

if you want to add more fields in select add the same in the group by too